# Sitemap_index.xml is not displayed

Tags: google-xml-sitemaps

When I want to check out my `/sitemap_index.xml` i get:

`http://mysite/post-sitemap.xml 2017-02-04T21:52:21+04:00 http://mysite/page-sitemap.xml 2017-01-31T17:16:39+04:00 http://mysite/testimonials-widget-sitemap.xml 2017-02-03T06:08:41+04:00`

What could be the problem. I am using Yoast Seo sitemap xml generator. The google google xml sitemaps is displaying the same.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use Stack Overflow in Russian, there is a WordPress tag.

Concerning your question, it seems everything is OK with your sitemap. Yoast SEO generates index sitemap mentioned in your question and several sitemaps for pages, posts, taxonomies, products in WooCommerce etc.

You can check this sitemap in Google Search Console, accessible via your Google account.